# Getting the least queue depth over a list of queues

Tags: list, mq

I have a list of MQ queues. Among the list of queues, I need to find the one which has the least depth. 
I can get the queue depth by using int depth= locQueue.getCurrentDepth(); But I dont know how to get the queue corresponding to the least queue depth.

For eg:

Q1  2
Q2  3
Q3  5
Q4  1

I need the Q3 as my output. Can someone help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of queues, then it would look something like this:

```
List<Queue> queues;

int indexOfLowest = -1;
int lowestCount = int.MaxValue;

foreach(var q in queues)
{
    if( q.Length < lowestCount )
    {
        indexOfLowest = queues.IndexOf( q );
        lowestCount = q.Length;
    }
}

var smallestQueue = queues.ElementAt( indexOfLowest );
```

Hopefully that helps, but I don't know what language you're working in.

Comment: Still very similar to the listed solution. I'm not to keen on java syntax so I can't update to accurately reflect exactly what you need, but your solution should look very similar to this.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try and let you know

Comment: No problem. If it works out, don't forget to upvote and mark as selected answer.

Comment: I didnt get the int lowestCount = int.MaxValue; what does int.MaxValue refers to?

Comment: int.MaxValue refers to the highest allowable value for an int. It's used so that any value found while searching through the queues will definitely be the lowest. If you set it to 0, smallestQueue will always be null. Set it to a huge number, like the max value of an int.